# averaging two rows in a matrix with mathematica

Tags: matrices, mathematica

If I have a $500 \times 500$ matrix and I would like to replace every ($5n-1$) row with the average of $(5n-1)$ and $(5n)$.  How would I be able to do this with *Mathematica*?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is the matrix. Then this should work:

```
ReplacePart[A, Map[(# -> (A[[#]] + A[[# + 1]])/2) &, Table[5 k-1, {k, 1, 100}]]]
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.